# How to prove gamma coefficient is zero, when (X,Y) is independent?

Tags: probability, statistics, solution-verification, independence

$\pi_c=P(concordant)=2P(X_1>X_2,Y_1>Y_2)=2E{(X_1>X_2,Y_1>Y_2)}$
$=2\sum_{i=1}^{I}\sum_{j=1}^{J}P[X_1>X_2=i,Y_1>Y_2=j]\pi_{ij}$$=2\sum_{i=1}^{I}\sum_{j=1}^{J}(\sum_{h>i}^{}\sum_{k>j}^{}\pi_{hk})$

$\pi_d=P(disconcordant)=2P(X_1>X_2,Y_1<Y_2)=2\sum_{i=1}^{I}\sum_{j=1}^{J}(\sum_{h>i}^{}\sum_{k<j}^{}\pi_{hk})$

The gamma coefficient is $\gamma=\frac{\pi_c+\pi_d}{\pi_c-\pi_d}$

Why gamma coefficient $=\pi_c-\pi_d=0$, when (X,Y) is independent?

Please show me the process.

I appreciate your any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $(X_1,Y_1)$ and $(X_2,Y_2)$ are i.i.d pairs of observations on $(X,Y)$.

Then probability of concordance and discordance is respectively

$$\pi_c=P\{(X_1-X_2)(Y_1-Y_2)>0\}$$

and $$\pi_d=P\{(X_1-X_2)(Y_1-Y_2)<0\}$$

If $X$ and $Y$ are independent and continuous, then $X_1$ and $X_2$ have the same distribution. Moreover, $X_1-X_2$ is independent of $Y_1-Y_2$.

Hence, under independence of continuous random variables,

\begin{align}
\pi_c&=P\{X_1>X_2\}P\{Y_1>Y_2\}+P\{X_1<X_2\}P\{Y_1<Y_2\}
\\&=P\{X_1<X_2\}P\{Y_1>Y_2\}+P\{X_1>X_2\}P\{Y_1<Y_2\}
\\&=P\{(X_1-X_2)(Y_1-Y_2)<0\}
\\&=\pi_d
\end{align}